# Gulp/uglify - bundle does not compress to bundle.js

Tags: gulp, browserify, gulp-uglify

This is my code

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserify = require('gulp-browserify');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

gulp.task('js', function () {
    gulp.src('js/main.js')
        .pipe(browserify())
        .pipe(rename('js/bundle.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));

})

gulp.task('watch', function () {

    gulp.watch('js/*.js', ['js']);
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
var gulp =       require('gulp');
var browserify = require('gulp-browserify');
var uglify =     require('gulp-uglify');
var source =     require('vinyl-source-stream');

gulp.task(
    browserify('js/main.js')
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('js/*.js', ['js']);
})
```